Why does the capacitance of a capacitor depend on charge and potential?
The formula of capacitance is
$$C = \frac{Q}{V}.$$
So the capacitance of a capacitor should depend on the charge and potential but it doesn't. Why?

Capacitance of a metal - what do you mean by that? A capacitor has two plates.

Because when you change Q, V varies in such a way that Q/V does not change?

I think you mean Capacitance of capacitor made with metal, In this case, It is infact the opposite, The capacitance is intrinsic property of any capacitor, This intrinsic property arises from the geometry of the components involved, primarily the arrangement and separation of conductive plates in a capacitor. In fact it is opposite of what you are saying, Even if you change $V$, $Q$ will changein a way so that $C$ is still constant

Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question with good answers below.

In Newtonian mechanics "acceleration of an object ($a$) = force applied on it($F$) / mass if the object ($m$) ". Does that mean m is dependent on $F$ and a as $m= F/a$ ? No! mass is an intrinsic property of that object that remains constant and  In fact $F/a$ depend on mass. Similarly Capacitance is intrinsic property of a Capacitor (not just metal like your spoon) which remains constant and on which $Q$ on the plates divided by voltage across the plates $V$ depend. It would be more clear if you read about Capacitors not just see formulas.

"acceleration of an object (a) = it's mass (m) × force applied on it(F) "
says $a=m\times F$. This is probably not what you mean.

Thx for pointing it out .  I made the biggest mistake in my life.


Formula of capacitance is C = Q/V So capacitance of metal should
depend on the charge and potential but it doesn't. Why?

That formula is for the electrical characteristics of the capacitor. It tells you the amount of net charge that can be held on each plates per volt applied across the plates.
The capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor depends on its physical properties per the equation
$$C=\frac{\epsilon A}{d}$$
Where $\epsilon$ is the electrical permittivity of the dielectric between the plates, $A$ the area of each plate, and $d$ the plate separation.
Hope this helps.

It is not generally true that the capacity or capacitance does not depend on the charge nor on the voltage. You could make a variable capacitor that adjusts C to keep V, or Q, constant. Then C would be proportional to Q, or V.
Edit: To exclude possible confusion with some readers: I assume the OP is asking about a metallic object, in particular a condenser.

To S K what do you understand as "Capacitance " of a metal? a single piece of metal has no capacity. So you seem not to mean capacity?

I don't understand your comment my2cts. asking what S K understands as capacitance is trying to help, why is it not "open mind?

@trula Is this a cross post?

It may be helpful to rewrite the equation for capacitance as $C=\frac{Q}{\Delta V}$.  This highlights that it's not the potential that the capacitor is at that matters, but rather the difference in voltage between the two sides of the capacitor (indeed, the "potential" is an arbitrary concept to begin with, while difference in potential is significant).
An ideal wire has no voltage drop, thus $\Delta V = 0$ and the above equation for $C$ is not meaningful.  It would include a divide by zero.  Of course, there is also no charge on an ideal wire, so it's a $\frac 0 0$ situation.
In non-ideal situations, we do have to consider the capacitance of wires.  Two nearby wires are a conductor-insulator-conductor trio.  That makes a capacitor.  The capacitance of such wires is very small, so we often get to ignore it.  However, in high speed circuits, such as those of memory modules in computers, we are very interested in such capacitance.
